# Passing data from container to component using Meteor React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I'm totally stuck with passing data from container to component When using Meteor and React. I thought I had just copied the code from Meteor React tutorial and customized a little bit, but it doesn't work somehow. What I wanna do is getting data from a database(QuestionModel) and simply output in a view. According to an error message in browser, this.props.questions in renderQuestions() is undefined... But I explicitly passed the data to the component. 
Could anyone help me out? Thank you.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { Questions as QuestionsModel } from '../../api/questions.js';
import { QuestionList } from '../QuestionList.jsx';

class Questions extends Component{
  renderQuestions(){
    let filteredQuestions = this.props.questions;
    //This doesn't work at all...
    console.log(this.props.questions);
    return filteredQuestions.map((question) => (
      <QuestionList key={question._id} question={question} />
    ));
  }
  render(){
    return (
        <div className="questionlist">
            <ul>{this.renderQuestions()}</ul>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

Questions.propTypes = {
  questions: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};


export default QuestionsContainer = createContainer(() => {
  //This console.log outputs the data correctly.
  console.log(QuestionsModel.find({}).fetch());
  const questions = QuestionsModel.find({}).fetch();
  return {
    questions,
  };
}, Questions);
```

Comment: Retun should be valid DOM element. Here You are returning `questions` which is not a valid DOM element.

Comment: Thanks you your replying. According to the official tutorial, container can return variable like array. This is not to render anything but merely to pass data to intended component. https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/collections 
What's weird is not being able to access the data from the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the code of your QuestionList component?

I just replaced it with `<li key={question._id}>{question.question}</li>` and it works perfectly for me.

Something else: do you import `/imports/api/questions.js';` server-side?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { Questions as QuestionsModel } from '../api/questions.js';
// import { QuestionList } from '../QuestionList.jsx';

class Questions extends Component{
  renderQuestions(){
    let filteredQuestions = this.props.questions;
    //This doesn't work at all...
    console.log(this.props.questions);
    return filteredQuestions.map((question) => (
      <li key={question._id}>{question.question}</li>
    ));
  }
  render(){
    return (
        <div className="questionlist">
            <ul>{this.renderQuestions()}</ul>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

Questions.propTypes = {
  questions: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};


export default QuestionsContainer = createContainer(() => {
  //This console.log outputs the data correctly.
  console.log(QuestionsModel.find().fetch());
  const questions = QuestionsModel.find({}).fetch();
  return {
    questions,
  };
}, Questions);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I might put a wrong path for the QuestionList, or QuestionList itself has an error. Anyways it works now. Thanks again.